# Css changes is only showing when I login to wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, html-table

I simply applied the below css:

```css
.StandardTable table th {
background: #0098B4 !important;
 color: #ffffff !important;
 text-align: center !important;
}

.StandardTable table tr {
background: #ffffff !important;
 color: #000000 !important;
}


.StandardTable table tr:hover{
    background-color:#1f2326 !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
}

.StandardTable table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
```

```html
<div class="StandardTable">
<table width="100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Country of Residency</th>
<th>UK</th>
<th>Malta</th>
<th>New Zealand</th>
<th>Australia</th>
<th>Gibraltar</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Albania</td>
<td>UK</td>
<td>Local</td>
<td>text</td>
<td>text</td>
<td>text</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

I can only see the changes if I log in to Wordpress, if I am just visiting the website as guest, the styles are not showing.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: It would help if you had a table in your live demo.

Comment: Sorry I totally forgot.

http://f9d.577.myftpupload.com/dta_analysis/

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: BTW, something about that page has royally broken scrolling on MacOS/Chrome.

Comment: https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Ff9d.577.myftpupload.com%2Fdta_analysis%2F

Comment: Using IE or Edge, click on the "Run code snippet" button in the question. Does it work correctly? If it does, please edit the code in the question so that it behaves the way you describe (doesn't work in IE or Edge but works in other browsers.)

Comment: @JJJ I am using Edge now and the code is working fine when I click Run code snippet.

but still if I load the website page, it's not showing correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's why there isn't enough information in the question. Add more code to the question so that it behaves the same way you describe.

Comment: @JJJ I don't know why I need to add more code, this is the only code I am using.

I've added this code in wordpress > custom css 

I believe the code is correct, but Edge is not loading the correct css?

Comment: Because, if you click on the Run code snippet, **it works on IE/Edge** like you said yourself. Therefore **the problem must be somewhere else** that you're not showing.

Comment: @JJJ I totally understand your point of view, but the only possible way to show you more code is to paste the entire css file, or to provide the page URL.

Comment: I am just a beginner with css and elements inspections using F12.

But thank you for your help so far. I will keep digging.

Comment: @jjj when I inspect the first cell of the table, I can see this code

media all {
 th {
    text-align:left;}
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have any caching plugins enabled on your site? Plugins like W3 Total Cache or Comet Cache?

If so, I would clear the cache using their tools or disable them if not needed.

You are probably seeing the changes when logged in because most of these plugins disable cache for you if you're signed in to the WP admin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

I don't have any Cache plugins installed.

Comment: Would you also rate up my question, I don't know why it has been rated down :(

Comment: Do you think it's good idea to install this plugin and try to clear the cache?

Answer (score 1):

Had simmilar issue, edited custom-css in Avada theme. Checked page, it had new css, but when I logged out page had old custom-css.Clear cache did not help. It was blog page, I had to go to that page in admin and press "update" for that page, to actually see new css.

Some weird stuff in wp.

Comment: I got exactly the same issue, also with Avada theme. Your solution worked. You save me hours!

Answer (score 0):

So I amusing Avada Theme.

I had to go to Theme Options > Advanced > Dynamic Css and JS > Disable CSS Compiling method.

Thanks Michael for the idea.

Answer (score -1):

It is simple.

If your css location is correct then just press **Ctrl+F5** and it will work.